# post to remote url from stand-alone html file

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to post to a remote url from a local html file on my desktop,  but the server doesn't seem o be receiving any post data?

Answer (score 1):

Oopsy, The designer didn't preserve the form input name attributes... (I just assumed they did)

Answer (score 0):

A form tag with action set to any web address will send to it:

```
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/myscript.php">
```

Take another look over your code to make sure you haven't forgotten anything. Showing us the HTML might help answers.